# Once Leave Approved, Power Automate will update another Table [URGENT help please]

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am creating a Leave Request Form in PowerApps, added Power Automate flow. Everything working fine.

Now, I need to update my LeaveBalance List (AppliedLeave Column) with the data from Leave List(TotalDays column) once the Leave is approved (from Email).

[image]

Need your urgent help and advice on this please.

Kind regards,

Santosh